# What is the best way to style the height for Sticky Header + Footer + Router Outlet: Angular 2 +

Tags: css, angular

I want to stack a Sticky Header + Router Outlet + Footer.  My issue is that the footer doesn't show and the Router Outlet either overflow or doesn't show as well.

I have tried using

```
<div class="container" style="position=relative">
    <header style="position:absolute"></header>
    <router-outlet style="position:absolute></router-outlet>
    <footer style="position:absolute></footer>
</div>
```

All (`min-height: fit-content`, `max-height:100vh`, `min-width: 100vw`).

I will also put a container in the nested component (router-outlet) to `min-height: 100vh`

Here is an output of what I am getting (using the suggestions provided below:   flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;). Notice how the footer is not sticking to the bottom despite the Position:absolute and bottom 0.

[image]

EDIT:
This was not a footer/container issue.  This proposed method I used theoretically worked.  Setting the correct CSS styles for the corresponding routed components affected the router-outlet as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try flex layout.

```
flex: auto;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Header and Footer height can be set.

Comment: for the container? Do I style the Nested Outlet Containers or the header/footer (height:100% for ex) ?

Comment: flex for container, header/footer can be set to a definite PX value or percentage.